# Error occurred while deserialize parameter http:tempuri.org/:

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, metadata, datacontract

I am Getting error while calling a WCF service via service proxy : Type [mytype]'1[system.collection.generic.list'1] cannot be added to list of known types since another type [mytype'1] with same data contract is already present.

Any idea how to resolve that ??

Coming after I have run svcutil for same host two times i.e. first time default (Array) and second time with adding /ct: parameter to generate with list type.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to Deserialize an XML data and failing the Schema checks.  You should only run the svcutil once.  You may need to modify you schema by adding an include.  Many xml schemas have optional types and to add your own type you  need to make minor changes to the standard schema.  the easiest way is to add an include statement to add a new child cschema.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp?force_isolation=true

Comment: Where should I add it as my reference file is class type ??

Comment: You should have a main XSD file which is a standard schema.  Then you should have a custom XSD Schema.  The include should be in the main XSD with the name of your custom XSD.  The type should be the root of your custom XSD and be the same name as a new (custom) type in the Main Schema.

Comment: xsd or wsdl file is not generated while adding service reference in .net core application

Comment: Apart from that, is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is a redefine that I've never used.  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_redefine.asp?force_isolation=true

Comment: For unknown types try to use KnownType: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types